# Reactjs functional component console value problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Test() {
  const [myState, setmyState] = useState(0);
  return (
      <div>
          <h2>JavaScript Lifecycle</h2>
          <button type="button" onClick={()=>{
              const val = myState+1;
              setmyState(val);
              console.log(myState);
          }}>Click This</button>
          <p>value:{myState}</p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked, the correct value of the state is written (near to value), but the old value is visible in the console. Sorting is correct, but when you need to send it to an api, it will go old. What can be done here? (I want to see the current value on the console)

Comment: The callback to onClick will always run to completion before react re-renders the component. There's absolutely nothing to prevent that except throwing an exception (which `setmyState` won't do). That's way you see the *old* value in the console. If you wanted to use the new state either use an `useEffect` hook, or simple use `val` (in your example).

Comment: This is work. Thank you for good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State has not been updated before `console.log` has been run. If you want to see new value, use `console.log(val)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `setmyState()` is an async function and the `console.log` is printing the value before the state has been set. To see the correct value in `console.log` you can use a callback.

refer to : `https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback` to get a better idea.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant whether `setmyState` is async or not. The code still must run through the whole function. That's why the console logs the *closed over* value of `myState`.

Comment: I am not saying code will not run...the code is running fine...its just that its showing old value in the log as `setMyState` is an async function here.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's irrelevant whether `setmyState` is async or not. Even if it weren't, it would still be the old value that would be logged in the console.

Comment: Yeah right...that's why i have asked to use the callback if you want to print the correct value.